# How to route dynamic routes to a single node while keeping the urls?

Tags: 8, routes, path-aliases

I have a node `node/1` with the path alias `/path`. What I want is for `/path/*` to always behave like you went to `/path`, but not change the url. So going to `/path/test?something=1` should behave identically to going to `/path` but the url will still be `/path/test?something=1` in the user's browser.

Right now, I'm getting a redirect loop when I return the same url in the `processOutbound` method. If I just return `$path` in this method, the user gets redirected to `/path?something=1`.

My use case is a vue app that has it's own routing. But we need a node to allow the client to edit the content around the app.

Code below. Thanks!

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\gm_custom;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;

class PathSubscriber implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * Processes the inbound path.
     *
     * @param string $path
     *   The path to process, with a leading slash.
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     *   The HttpRequest object representing the current request.
     *
     * @return string
     *   The processed path.
     */
    public function processInbound($path, Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->stringStartsWith('/plan/', strtolower($path))) {
            return '/node/1';
        }

        return $path;
    }

    public function processOutbound(
        $path,
        &$options = [],
        Request $request = null,
        BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = null
    ) {
        $url = strtok($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ], '?');
        if ($this->stringStartsWith('/plan/', $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ])) {
            return $url;
        }

        return $path;
    }


    protected function stringStartsWith($needle, $haystack)
    {
        return (substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I've confirmed it's the redirect module is the issue. Simply installing it creates the above problem. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Path processing doesn't redirect, do you have the Redirect module installed? Also, only use the request object to get the URI and query parameters. The returned path should not contain the query string. Put the query parameters in $options['query'].

Comment: Confirmed it's the redirect module! Just simply installing it without any additional config causes this problem. Thanks for the tips. Still looking into it, will report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Alright got it working! The redirect module hooks into the `kernel.request` event and will redirect if you're doing wildcard routing like I am below.

You may want to split this up into two services since we're hooking into two events, but they're directly related so I chose to keep it simple.
Basic explanation of methods in here is:

**PathSubscriber::processInbound**
Check the incoming url and map it to a single node

**PathSubscriber::getSubscribedEvents**
Register our callback for the `kernel.request` aka `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event so we can stop the redirect module from redirecting.

**PathSubscriber::stopRedirectIfOurRoute**
Check the path and if it matches against our wildcard routing from `PathSubscriber::processInbound` then set the `_disable_route_normalizer` to `true` to disable the redirect module from redirecting to the node's alias. Leave our urls alone!

---

**mymodule/src/PathSubscriber.php**

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class PathSubscriber implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * Processes the inbound path.
     *
     * @param string $path
     *   The path to process, with a leading slash.
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     *   The HttpRequest object representing the current request.
     *
     * @return string
     *   The processed path.
     */
    public function processInbound($path, Request $request)
    {
        if (self::stringStartsWith('/plan/', strtolower($path))) {
            return '/node/1';
        }

        return $path;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // register our event right before the redirect module redirects
        $events[ KernelEvents::REQUEST ][] = ['stopRedirectIfOurRoute', 31];

        return $events;
    }

    /**
     * ------------------------------------
     * From the redirect module (redirect/src/EventSubscriber/RouteNormalizerRequestSubscriber.php):
     *
     * The normalization can be disabled by setting the "_disable_route_normalizer"
     * request parameter to TRUE. However, this should be done before
     * onKernelRequestRedirect() method is executed.
     * ------------------------------------
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     *   The event to process.
     */
    public static function stopRedirectIfOurRoute(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $path = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo();

        if (self::stringStartsWith('/plan/', strtolower($path))) {
            $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('_disable_route_normalizer', true);
        }
    }

    public static function stringStartsWith($needle, $haystack)
    {
        return (substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle);
    }
}
```

---

**mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.path_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\PathSubscriber
    tags:
     - { name: path_processor_inbound }
     - { name: event_subscriber }
```